# Is it possible to create custom indexes in Agenda 4.4?

Tags: indexing, agenda

It looks that the answer is affirmative in version 5.0.0 of Agenda, but I was wondering if there is such feature in version [4.4.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda/v/4.4.0). The only reference to indexes that I have found is to disable the default index when you instantiate Agenda, as follows:

```
const myAgenda = new Agenda({
  ...
  disableAutoIndex: true,
  ...
})
```

But this only enable/disable the default index created by Agenda.

Currently working with MongoDB, but I think that database is irrelevant in this case.